# How can I avoid naming my variables the same thing as my method names in ruby?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I've been trying to keep my methods short, and in doing so end up with lines like:

`processor = processor(arg1, arg2)`

Where it makes a lot of sense for the variable to have the same name as the method. So then I've heard I can use `self.` to clarify in this one line that I'm using the method, but that still seems like it would cause problems down the line for the interpreter, not to mention anyone reading the code. But prefixing methods with `get_` also feels weird. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem with `processor = processor(arg1, arg2)` in the first place? It’s legit, you don’t need any `self` and/or `get_`.

Comment: what does the `processor` method do? there might be a better name for it? `build_processor` ? Other than that: see comment by @mudasobwa.

Comment: Perhaps it is just me but I do not understand the question. You can name variables and method whatever you want to. Just choose the most suitable name. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Maybe you can refactor that to `processor = Processor.new(arg1, arg2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically there is nothing wrong with what you're doing, but it does have potential to make your code a bit confusing to read. You could use the instance variable `@processor` instead of the local variable `processor`, to make the difference between variable and method more obvious, but depending on where you're using it this could have side effects as it will be available throughout `self`, not just in the local scope.

Alternatively, since your local variable isn't adding much value in terms of readability, you could simply call the method directly wherever you need its return value.

Your version:

```
processor = processor(:arg1, :arg2)
# do some stuff
do_something_else_with(processor)
```

Consuming the return value directly:

```
do_something_else_with(processor(:arg1, :arg2))
```

---

It's also worth noting that if your method had arity 0 (i.e. no arguments) then you would run into problems – as you say, you'd have to use `self` or add empty parentheses (very un-ruby-like) to your method call:

```
def processor
 return 'something'
end

processor = processor
#=> nil

processor
#=> nil 

processor = processor()
#=> 'something'

processor = self.processor
#=> 'something'
```

Ultimately it's in your interest to just use distinct names in the first place. Not easy but worth spending time on. As a wise man [once tweeted](https://twitter.com/secretGeek/status/7269997868), "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors".

Comment: By distinct names, you mean, a distinct name for the variable and a distinct name for the method?

Comment: just so. For example, in the case in your question, I might go for `processed = process(x)`